# How can I get a value from youtube api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-api, dialogflow-es

I'm building a chatbot that retrieves a youtube link based on what the user has asked.
I'm using Dialogflow for the bot and using nodejs for the coding.

Right now, everything works perfectly but my problem is retrieving the link from the API response.
using console.dir(results), shows the following:
This is how the response looks like:

```
[ { id: 'gWNUg_v25dw',
link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWNUg_v25dw',
kind: 'youtube#video',
publishedAt: '2017-08-24T14:00:11.000Z',
channelId: 'UCDZ56yQ05d_ikcwcTG9bAiA',
channelTitle: 'Code to Create',
title: 'How to make a Chatbot with Dialogflow - API.ai',
description: 'In this video, Google Developer Expert, Faisal Abid will show us how to create a chatbot with Google\'s latest API.ai API.ai can be integrated with multiple chat ...',
thumbnails: { default: [Object], medium: [Object], high: [Object] } } ]
```

I have tried using results.link to retrieve the link but Im getting undefined, so my question is how to retrieve the link from the response block?

```
search(txt1, opts, function(err, results) {
//var data1 = JSON.parse(results);
//srchRes = data1.link;
if(err) return console.log(err);


console.dir(results);
});
```

uncommenting the 2 lines above and console.dir(srchRes) returns this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have your API call code logic so from here, **we could only assume** `results` is the API's response and given your exemple about how the response look like, then we see `results` is an array of object.

- [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/parse) actually deserialize a string which represent an object given the JSON format.
- [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/stringify) is the contrary, it serialize your object to a string with the JSON format.

Your goal is to reach the `link` properties of a **particular** object **within** the array, which is why `JSON.parse(results)` makes no sense.

You should be able to reach `link`properties for each object by simply iterate over the array of object `results`

```
for (const result of results) {
    console.log(`the link : ${result.link}`)
}
```

Comment: Using that got me the link correctly, and I'm using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-search and thanks for the extra info about the JSON format.

Comment: Glad it helps, happy coding